# Filter objects in Django 2 if all objects in subquery have specific value

Tags: python, django, filter, subquery, django-queryset

I have the follow models:

```
class FactoryDevice(models.Model)
    ...

class InspectionRegister(models.Model)
    factory_device = models.ForeignKey(FactoryDevice)
    inspection_date = models.DateTimeField()
    status = models.CharField(choices=choices.STATUS)
```

This is the scenario:

In a factory, every week devices are inspected.

I want filter only `FactoryDevice`s that the last five related `InspectionRegister`s have status as `choices.REPPROVED`. If one of the last five `InspectionRegister` in a `FactoryDevice` not has status as `choices.REPPROVED` so this `FactoryDevice` must not be in the results.

Comment: I assume status is some sort of `IntegerField`? Since now it is not a column in the database at all.

Comment: What should happen to devices that have no five `InspectionRegister`s?

Comment: If a device has less than five it does not have be present in results

Comment: Fixed the status in model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I would define a `related_name` for your reverse relationship to make your life easier:

```
factory_device = models.ForeignKey(FactoryDevice, related_name='inspections')
```

Then something like this could work:

```
queryset = FactoryDevice.objects
.prefetch_related(Prefetch(
    'inspections', # your related name
    InspectionRegister.objects.order_by('-inspection_date')[:5].filter(status=choices.REPPROVED),
    to_attr='failed_inspections'
)
.annotate(failed_count=Count('failed_inspections'))
)
.filter(failed_count__gte=5)
```

Comment: To count only `InspectionRegister`s with status equals to `choices.REPPROVED` could be something like this?

`... Count(Case(When(late_five_inspections__status=choices.REPPROVED, then=1), output_field=CharField())) ... `

Comment: A little confused by the context of that query. I would do something like:
`
FactoryDevice.objects.filter(inspections__status=choices.REPPROVED).annotate(num_failed_inspections=Count('inspections'))
`

Comment: It must be considered consecutive values. If the last five consecutives values are 'choices.REPPROVED'

Comment: Thats why I first do the `order_by('-inspection_date')[:5]`. I'm basically sorting the inspections by date order, then taking the latest 5. After that is when we see if those 5 latest inspections are all the failed status.

Comment: Now I have a error with `(When(failed_inspections__status=choices.REPPROVED, then=1)`. In [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/queries/#prefetch-objects): "When using to_attr the prefetched result is stored in a list", so, `failed_inspections` doesn't have `__status`.

If I use the related `inspections`, it doesn't follow the `order_by` and the limit `[:5]. It gets all related objects.

Comment: Try it now. Sorry I can't test it locally but I just moved all the InspectionRegister filtering inside the prefetch statement so it won't re-evaluate the query later.